# Problem Showing ProgressDialog within Nested Tab Activity

Tags: android, android-tabhost, progressdialog

I am Having Nested Tab Activity.

TabMain (TabHost) with that i have ChildTab (another TabHost) and other 2 Activities.

I can able to show Progress Dialog in that other 2 activity.

But with in ChildTab TabActivity I add 5 Activities

in that i can able to Show progressDialog.

I am getting the following error.

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@43d304f0 is not valid; is your activity running?

Comment: How are you trying to show the dialog?

Comment: ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(T11.this, "Loading...", "Please wait..."); this way..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try   `ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getParent(), "Loading...", "Please wait...");`

...I think it will make things worinkg   .

Comment: Ya getParent() worked very well Buddy...Thank you... But its showing After some time i am using thread to get data from internet and update it in UI here it shows black screen for first 1 or 2 seconds and then its showing progressDialog , do you know why?

Comment: No I am using simple thread for network activity and UI thread

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I found this error too and became mad till I found the solution. 
The answer above is correct but in my case I had a nested application formed by tabs/activity groups in/more activity groups and a single activity inside. You need to go up as many levels as you need till you get the context of the application. In my case there were two:

```
public static Activity goUp(Activity current){
        if(current.getParent()!=null){
            current=current.getParent();
            goUp(current);
        }
        return current;
    }
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(goUp(MyActivity.this), "Loading...", "Please wait...");
```

Answer (score 2):

Ugly solution :

```
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            parent = (ConfigurarionStyleAndroidGUI) getParent();            
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.ui_settings);
            EditTextPreference p = (EditTextPreference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference(getString(R.string.key_settings_style_name));
            forceContext(parent,p);
        }
        private void forceContext(Context context,Preference p){
        try {
            Field field = Preference.class.getDeclaredField("mContext");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(p, parent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If getParent() doesn't work for you, try using just `TabsActivity.context` (or substitute the name of your parent tab activity class). I am using nested activities and as a result using getParent() is still not returning the right context for the dialog.

After trying 20 different variations of the suggestions above I replaced this line:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

With:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(TabsActivity.context);
```

and it worked like a charm. You'll also need to create the context variable in the TabsActivity class. Something like `public static TabsActivity context;` and `context=this` in the onCreate method.