# TabActivity with ActivityGroup and PreferenceActivity child

Tags: android, tabactivity, preferenceactivity, activitygroup

I have a TabActivity where each tab has ActivityGroup.
On the home ActivityChild of the first group I have an menu option, which gives to the user the option to open preferences.
When I click "Preferences" on menu, I start PreferenceActivity inside ActivityGroup, which shows PreferenceActivity on the first tab.
The problem is when I click on any specific preference which has to show a Dialog (for EditTextPreference).
I have the following exception:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@405d3a20
```

I understand that the problem is because Dialog to be shown by PreferenceActivity uses wrong context, BUT i don't now how change the context of created dialog.

Belows is the PreferenceActivity I've created.

```
public class PreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity  implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.preferences);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,String key) {     

    }   
}
```

I don't want to create custom dialogs. I want to use the mechanism of PreferenceActivity for that.
Below is the code that I'm using to add to group:

```
i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, PreferencesActivity.class);
TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity) getParent();
parentActivity.startChildActivity("PreferencesActivity", i);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Add your code when you create the dialog.

Comment: I didn't use any implementation of to control the way how dialogs to be created. I simply extended PreferenceActivity and onCreate I've added addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

Comment: Bad solution [HERE][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877112/problem-showing-progressdialog-within-nested-tab-activity/8191979#8191979

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This is very common problem with dialog's in Tab Host.

Actually the Activity context is not sufficient to show a Dialog in Tab.


You have to use the context of your GroupActivity for the dialog to be enabled without exception
```

Comment: Hi, I don't use custom Dialogs, that's why I don't now how pass correct context. Because if I control creation of dialogs I would use getParent() as context.

Comment: Just you are having context problem.. In case of Root TabActivity always use context of Tab Activity even for the the Individual Activities in tab

Comment: I added more code, maybe you can understand better my problem.

Comment: As a workaround I started PreferenceActivity outside of ActivityGroup as a separate activity. Anyway thanks for comments.